# Return HTML and JS rendered in Flask by one function without running it twice

Tags: python, flask

I am dynamically generating HTML and JS based on a user query. The HTML is served as `"page.html?query..."` and links to the JS `"page.js?query..."`.

Currently, the same function generates both the HTML and JS. This function is called twice, once from the HTML view, which extracts and uses the HTML part of the result, and once from the JS view, which extracts and uses the JS part of the result. This is inefficient.

An obvious alternative would be to include the JS *inline*, but this violates the Content Security Policy. I could also split the view function into two different functions, one for HTML and one for JS. Aside from being programmatically messy, this however still means I need to run all my SQL queries twice.

I'd like to generate the JS and HTML together, but maintain the separation dictated by the CSP. Does Flask (or any framework) provide a way around this?

Comment: Why are you dynamically generating your JavaScript? Typically, once something is JavaScript, the source file itself does not need to be changed by user input or anything else; only when you want to change the logic.

Comment: @Thomas I'm not generating *everything*, but parts are - to pass data, to set event handlers, from optional elements. Much like the page we are viewing right now!

Comment: Could you give a code example? I have never seen JavaScript be dynamically generated; it has always been a static resource. I might be wrong, but I don't think StackOverflow would dynamically generate their JS simply because this would mean it would be very difficult to cache.

Comment: @Thomas e.g. `StackExchange.question.init({votesCast:[],canViewVoteCounts:true,totalCommentCount:3,shownCommentCount:3,highlightColor:'#F4A83D',backgroundColor:'#FFF',questionId:57273528});`, as you can see, the values are inserted inline. Also, as I mention in the question, if you use CSP there isn't much choice.

Comment: There's the common SO meme of "don't do what you want to do and do this instead" but... I think other options might be better (security, performance/network bandwidth through caching). Why not have a static JS script that calls a web service endpoint (you're already using Flask), returns JSON, and parses that? Why not store HTML attributes in the markup, e.g.: `<div first_name="Alice">/* ... */</div>` and having static JS interpret that on load?

Comment: Anyway, I don't want to be unhelpful. I understand what you're trying to do, so when I get back home I'll give this question a crack.